# Xpages - Adding a Key to NotesViewNavigator

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs, domino-designer-eclipse

I'm returning values from two different columns but will like to narrow down the results by using a key.

[image]

And below is my code which returns all. Efforts to use keys returns in mistypes.

```
var v:NotesView = database.getView("myView");
var key = getComponent("key").getValue();
var nav:NotesViewNavigator = v.createViewNavFromCategory(key);
//solved by replacing-v.createViewNav();
var entry:NotesViewEntry = nav.getFirst();
var list = new java.util.Vector(); 
while (entry != null) {
   var tabs:string = "";
   for (var i=0; i<entry.getIndentLevel(); i++) tabs = tabs + "\t";
   requestScope.status += "\n" + tabs + entry.getColumnValues().elementAt(entry.getIndentLevel()).toString();
list.addElement(entry.getColumnValues().elementAt(entry.getIndentLevel()).toString());
   var tmpentry:NotesViewEntry = nav.getNextCategory();
   entry.recycle();
   entry = tmpentry;
}
print(requestScope.status);
return list;
```

Will be pleased with your help.

Comment: Have you tried *createViewNavFromCategory* instead of *createViewNav*?

Comment: That worked. Thanks Sven.